# Ensuring minimum update frequency of a pyglet application

Tags: python, pyglet

Function calls triggered by `pyglet.clock.schedule_interval()` seem to occur at *extremely* variable time intervals after the pyglet window is hidden/minimized (this is on macOS Catalina, in case it matters).

Below is a minimal example that should print out a number not much greater than 0.5 every half second. Instead, after a few seconds of the window being minimized, calls are delayed by up to 10 seconds.

I'm (baselessly) assuming this is because pyglet is designed to function with lower priority when the window is not visible. I dont really care if my functions calls occur every 0.6 seconds instead of 0.5, but a 10s lag seems unreasonably large.

Is there a simple way to ensure pyglet maintains a high priority and/or does not drastically alter the frequency of scheduled calls?

```py
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(width = 128, height = 128)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()

def foo(t):
    print(t)

pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(foo, 0.5)
pyglet.app.run()
```

Typical output below:

```
0.5010913940000137
8.22102221900002
10.501081690999968
10.501448707999998
10.501421234999953
3.7303194810000377
10.501095133000035
0.5011976460000369
10.501220476999947
10.501225187000045
4.144422970999926
```